# How to connect web2py with mongodb on localhost?

Tags: mongodb, web2py

Someone please tell me how to connect web2py with mongodb on localhost?
Also tell me is web2py dead? I cant find proper community of web2py.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with mongodb. But the official web2py community is here:
https://groups.google.com/g/web2py

Here is the top hit on mongodb:
https://groups.google.com/g/web2py/c/gR_zsk6ufns/m/U6UAdki4AgAJ
Maybe it helps you.

web2py is still alive but it is being replaced with py4web.  Community for that is here:
https://groups.google.com/g/py4web

Six months ago py4web was just starting to get good traction with the web2py community. If you are starting a new project then py4web is definitely recommended. I stuck with web2py because of the documentation and many historical posts that I found invaluable.